# how to validate xml and dtd with online resource

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to use http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to validate the xml and dtd, but got error while processing the dtd. I add  for the dtd, but it doesn't work. I wonder what's missing. I copied and pasted both files onto one page(didn't use external). 
Thanks!

```
<Bookstore>
<Book ISBN = "ISBN-101" Price = "100" Authors = "JU JW">
    <Title>
        Introduction to Python
    </Title>    
</Book>
<Book ISBN = "ISBN-202" Price = "120" Authors = "HG JU JW">
    <Title>
        Digital Circuit Design
    </Title>
    <Remark>
        Amazon.com says: Buy this book bundled with
        <BookRef book = "ISBN-303" /> - a great deal!
    </Remark>       
</Book>

<Author Ident = "HG">
    <Firstname>Hector</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Garcia</Lastname>
</Author>
<Author Ident = "JU">
    <Firstname>Jeffrey</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Ullman</Lastname>
</Author>
<Author Ident = "JW">
    <Firstname>Jennifer</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Widom</Lastname>
</Author>
```

```
<!ELEMENT Bookstore(Book*, Author*)>
<!ELEMENT Book (Title, Remark?)>
<!ATTLIST Book ISBN ID #REQUIRED
          Price CDATA #REQUIRED
          Authors IDREFS #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Remark(#PCDATA | BookRef)*>
<!ELEMENT BookRef EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST BokkRef book IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Author(Firstname,Lastname)>
<!ATTLIST Author Ident ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Firstname(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Lastname(#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the DTD and XML instance, add a DOCTYPE declaration and put the DTD declarations in the internal subset (add a [prolog](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog))...

```
<!DOCTYPE Bookstore [
<!ELEMENT Bookstore (Book*, Author*)>
<!ELEMENT Book (Title, Remark?)>
<!ATTLIST Book ISBN ID #REQUIRED
          Price CDATA #REQUIRED
          Authors IDREFS #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Remark (#PCDATA | BookRef)*>
<!ELEMENT BookRef EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST BookRef book IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Author (Firstname,Lastname)>
<!ATTLIST Author Ident ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Lastname (#PCDATA)>
]>
<Bookstore>
    <Book ISBN="ISBN-101" Price="100" Authors="JU JW">
        <Title>
            Introduction to Python
        </Title>    
    </Book>
    <Book ISBN="ISBN-202" Price="120" Authors="HG JU JW">
        <Title>
            Digital Circuit Design
        </Title>
        <Remark>
            Amazon.com says: Buy this book bundled with
            <BookRef book="ISBN-303"/> - a great deal!
        </Remark>       
    </Book>

    <Author Ident="HG">
        <Firstname>Hector</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Garcia</Lastname>
    </Author>
    <Author Ident="JU">
        <Firstname>Jeffrey</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Ullman</Lastname>
    </Author>
    <Author Ident="JW">
        <Firstname>Jennifer</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Widom</Lastname>
    </Author>
</Bookstore>
```

I fixed some typos in the DTD declarations, but your file still has an issue with an invalid IDREF (missing the corresponding ID).